# getFromLocationName alwayd return empty address

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I'm a bit confused, I'm trying to retrieve Latitude / Longitude from an adress, I retrieved some code from previous posts but whatever the address I'm filling in the getFromLocationName method, I'm always having an empty string in return.

here is the code I'm using:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    LatLng coord = getLocationFromAddress(getBaseContext(), fullAdr);
```

.....
.....

```
    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress)
{
    Geocoder coder= new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try
    {
        if(!coder.isPresent()) {
            Log.d("JRE","There is no GeoCoder !");
            return new LatLng(0,0);
        }
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if(address==null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p1;

}
```

any idea why I'm getting always empty values ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty string" here? The code you've posted returns a LatLng. Is the problem that no Address objects are returned?

Comment: yes that's right, address  is empty so not possible to extract LatLng